# How can I run my react-native app on my physical Samsung S9 phone?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I know there are documents on this, but I have no clue how to get the app to actually show up on the phone. All I get after running is a Node.js window on my PC instead of phone.

Comment: What command are you running to try to make the app run? react-native run-android?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Expo for this purpose. There is a link to it https://expo.io/

It's pretty easy to set up and use.
When you run it from, for example, Visual Studio Code you can run it on your real device, just installing Expo app from AppStore/GooglePlay (Scan the QR code) as well as on PC in Android Studio etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `expo`**

Expo enables you to run your react-native app on your local android or iOS simulator as well as physical devices.

Comment: If the app was not set up with expo but rather with the react-native cli, then expo won't be of much help.

Comment: Yes that's true. But in that case we could use [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device)

Comment: Yes exactly, which is why we need to know whether they are using the react-native cli or the expo-cli.